# Handling Entity Framework 5 .Include() method when using binding redirection and EF6 dlls

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got the setup below:

[image]

In my AwesomeApp, I use a binding redirect in order to load EF6 when EF

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" 
                      publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" 
                      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Everything works EXCEPT a EF5 .Include() call - when I invoke that call, I get the following exception:

[image]

Is there a workaround here?

Comment: Why exactly are you using two different versions of EF?

Comment: Old legacy code + more recently written app = fun times.... Not my choice or under my control :-/

Comment: Couldn't you just use EF6? Does EF6 not have .Include anymore?

Comment: I believe it's not in the same namespace as EF5 so the binding redirect doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure your version of EF 6 is 6.0.0.0?

Comment: Well, it's 6.1.3.0 but I think you have to use 6.0.0.0 for binding / binding redirection